# Ruby execution getting stuck in a single thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, infinite-loop

I am trying to listen on a socket while performing other tasks but my program just gets stuck in the listening loop and can't do anything else.  The code I'm using is:

```
t = Thread.new do
  @listener.listen
end
t.join

puts('do more stuff')
```

Where `@listener.listen` is:

```
def listen

  puts('listening')
  while true
    data = p @socket.recv(1000)      # Receive
    respond(JSON.parse(data))
  end
end
```

If I do this the program gets stuck in the while loop and "do more stuff" is never printed.  Anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to call `join`. `join` waits for its thread to finish.

Comment: If I get rid of the join however while loop isn't executed.  The program gets into the listen function, prints 'listening' and then immediately exits the function.

Comment: Then probably there is some exception being thrown inside your loop. Having quick look this is caused by p method which returns nil, whcih you are trying to parse later with JSON. If you want display value of data, move p before data

Answer (score 1):

Threads are not a good fit. Basically, what you need is a loop which sets a callback on a new task and moves to the next task. You might want to check the event-loop approach using [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com).

Try setting `abort_on_exception` to check for exceptions and a timeout in seconds:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
t = Thread.new do
  @listener.listen
end
t.join(5) #Does not return until all threads exit or 5 sec(timeout) have passed.
```

Also, in `listen?`:

```
def listen

  puts('listening')
  while true
    data = p @socket.recv(1000)      # Receive
    respond(JSON.parse(data))
  end
end
```

You have a infinite loop `while true`. Do you check to see if it ever returns false?

```
def listen

  puts('listening')
  loop do
    data = p @socket.recv(1000)      # Receive
    result = respond(JSON.parse(data))
    if result
      puts "Still True."
    else
      puts "Got False. Exiting loop.."
      break
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As far as I can see, he doesn't want to exit the loop.

Comment: If that's the case, then how will Thread#close ever complete on its own without Except/Timeout? Because all the child will ALWAYS be stuck in this loop. Perhaps, for this sort of thing, we might want to check the event-loop approach using http://rubyeventmachine.com/

Comment: Yeah @BroiSatse is right in saying that I don't want to exit the loop.  I want the program to continuously listen on the socket while continuing to do other things on another thread.  I tried putting a print statement at the start of the loop and it never gets printed so it doesn't seem to be getting into the loop at all.

Comment: In that case, threads are not good fit. basically, you need is a loop running loop which set a callback on a new task & moves to next task. we might want to check the event-loop approach using EventMachine. rubyeventmachine.com